# Need help fixing a recursion method regarding not printing multiples of an output with consecutive inputs

Tags: java

This is for an assignment for my college class. Normally I would just email my teacher, but its 11 at night. The method that i need help with is printsparsetablehelp. it uses the fibby method to calculate n. some fibby calculations are the same as the previous. printsparsetable is used to not print the copies. for example fibby of 8 9 and 10 all of the same output. It should only print 8. My issue is that it is printing out the right numbers but for some reason it's going back into the method and lowering the start value and reprinting some of the numbers. I am calling this method with the start 5 and the end 10. it should come back with 5 6 6 8 8 11.

```
public static int fibby(int n) {
        if(n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return fibby(n/4) + fibby((3*n)/4);
    }

    public static void printsparsetable(int start, int end) {
        printsparsetablehelp(start, end, start);
    }
    public static void printsparsetablehelp(int start, int end, int initialStart) {
        if(start == initialStart) {
            System.out.println(start + " " + fibby(start));
            printsparsetablehelp(start + 1, end, initialStart);
        }
        if(start > end) {
        } else {
            if(fibby(start) == fibby(start - 1)) {
                if(start + 1 <= end) {
                    printsparsetablehelp(start + 1, end, initialStart);
                }
            } else {
                if(start <= end) {
                    System.out.println(start + " " + fibby(start));
                    if(start + 1 <= end) {
                        printsparsetablehelp(start + 1, end, initialStart);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - it's hard to know what you're trying to do.  Is there any chance you can just ask your teacher for help tomorrow?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, I have to question the validity of this comment. the question is not clear to you. fine. vote to close. the "solution" suggestion is really unhelpful

Comment: if anyone wants more clarifications on the question: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/assignment-implement-recursive-methods-java-class-called-recursionintro-please-make-use-ja-q21159273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the first condition (`if(start == initialStart)`) is wrong and leads to extra computations.

I suggest combining it with the `fibby(start) == fibby(start - 1)` condition.

```
public static void printsparsetablehelp(int start, int end, int initialStart) {
    if(start <= end) {
        if(start > initialStart && fibby(start) == fibby(start - 1)) {
            if(start + 1 <= end) {
                printsparsetablehelp(start + 1, end, initialStart);
            }
        } else {
            if(start <= end) {
                System.out.println(start + " " + fibby(start));
                if(start + 1 <= end) {
                    printsparsetablehelp(start + 1, end, initialStart);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which can be further simplified to

```
public static void printsparsetablehelp(int start, int end, int initialStart) {
    if(start <= end) {
        if(start == initialStart || fibby(start) != fibby(start - 1)) {
            System.out.println(start + " " + fibby(start));
        }
        if(start + 1 <= end) {
            printsparsetablehelp(start + 1, end, initialStart);
        }
    }
}
```

and if you know for certain that start <= end in the initial call to `printsparsetablehelp`, it can be further simplified:

```
public static void printsparsetablehelp(int start, int end, int initialStart) {
    if(start == initialStart || fibby(start) != fibby(start - 1)) {
        System.out.println(start + " " + fibby(start));
    }
    if(start + 1 <= end) {
        printsparsetablehelp(start + 1, end, initialStart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I knew it was something super simple that I was overlooking. Thank you so much @Eran